# How to 'fit' eigen-words to actual words for initial wordle guess

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, puzzle

I got thinking about how I could use eigenvector analysis to find "optimal" initial word guesses for [Wordle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html).  I'm not sure if my approach has any merit, and I'm curious if others would have any input.  Here's my approach.

1. Get the list of all valid wordle words from [here - https://github.com/tabatkins/wordle-list](https://github.com/tabatkins/wordle-list).
2. Represent each word in a Nx26 matrix where each column represents a letter in the alphabet.
3. Calculate the eigen-vectors of this matrix.
4. For the top M eigen-values/vectors, find the "best" words that represent these eigenvectors. This is where I think I'm most confused.  I don't know how best to "fit" actual words to the eigenwords.  Here's a couple of approaches I'm trying (although the two approaches give quite different words!)  **Which is better?** The sum of square approach is sensitive to the mean of the matrix (which makes sense).  It also seems to prefer words with repeats of highly ranked letter in the eigenword:

   a. Vector multiply the words by the eigenword.  The highest values are ranked as the "best" fits.

   b. Calculate the sum of squared errors from the actual words and the eigen words.  Those with least error are the "best" fits.

I'm subtracting the mean of the columns of the Nx26 matrix.  I think that's necessary for the eigenvalue calculation but not sure if it should be there for the ranking.

Here's a full python script of my approach:

```
"""
https://bert.org/assets/posts/wordle/words.json
"""
import numpy as np
import json


def get_words():
    """
    words file is from: 
    https://github.com/tabatkins/wordle-list

    'herrings' and 'solutions' from here
    https://bert.org/assets/posts/wordle/words.json
    """
    # words = []
    # with open('words') as f:
        # for word in f.readlines():
            # words.append(word.strip())
    # return words
    return json.load(open('words.json'))


def words2mat(words):
    """
    n_words x 26 matrix
    """
    mat = np.zeros((len(words), 26), dtype=int)

    for n, word in enumerate(words):
        for l in word:
            idx = ord(l) - ord('a')
            #mat[n, idx] += 1
            mat[n, idx] = 1  # We don't care if the letter occurs multiple times.

    return mat # - mat.mean(axis=0)


def eigen_words(mat):

    X = mat - mat.mean(axis=0)

    # Covariance Matrix
    W = X.T @ X

    evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(W)

    # Sort largest first
    idx = np.argsort(evals)[::-1]
    evals = evals[idx]
    evecs = evecs[:, idx]
    
    return evals, evecs


def value_letter(evec):
    """
    Create a list of (letter, value) for inspection of eigenword
    """
    return [(chr(n + ord('a')), evec[n].round(2)) for n in range(26)]


def eigen_words_best_matches(words, mat, evec):
    ranks = (mat @ evec).flatten()
    # Return the top 4 matching words to the eigen-word
    idx = ranks.argsort()[-1:-5:-1]

    # Calculate the sum of squares of the residuals from the eigen-word.  A lower
    # value means the word is closer to the eigen-word.
    res = ((mat - evec) ** 2).sum(axis=1)
    idx2 = res.argsort()[:4]
    
    return np.array(words)[idx2].tolist(), res[idx2], np.array(words)[idx].tolist(), res[idx]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    words = get_words()
    mat = words2mat(words['solutions'])
    evals, evecs = eigen_words(mat)

    # Look at the top 3 eigenwords
    for n in range(3):
        vl = sorted(value_letter(evecs[:, n]), key=lambda x: x[1])
        print(f"Eigenword {n}")
        print(f"   Top 5 'positive' letters in eigenword {n}: {vl[-1:-6:-1]}")
        print(f"   Top 5 'negative' letters in eigenword {n}: {vl[:5]}")
        sq_err_words, sq_err_vals, vector_prod_words, vector_prod_vals = eigen_words_best_matches(words['solutions'] + words['herrings'], mat, evecs[:, n])
        print(f"   Vector product ranked words {vector_prod_words}")
        print(f"   Squared error ranked words  {sq_err_words}")
        print()

    # What percentage of variation is represented by the top n eigenwords?
    for n in range(1, 5):
        print(f"{evals[:n].sum() / evals.sum() * 100:.0f}% of variation is captured by the first {n} eigenwords.")
```

Which has the output of:

```
Eigenword 0
   Top 5 'positive' letters in eigenword 0: [('o', 0.2), ('i', 0.19), ('y', 0.17), ('u', 0.17), ('n', 0.17)]
   Top 5 'negative' letters in eigenword 0: [('e', -0.7), ('r', -0.5), ('a', -0.17), ('v', -0.06), ('d', -0.05)]
   Vector product ranked words ['noisy', 'unity', 'lousy', 'stony']
   Squared error ranked words  ['onion', 'ninny', 'sissy', 'slyly']

Eigenword 1
   Top 5 'positive' letters in eigenword 1: [('o', 0.36), ('r', 0.33), ('i', 0.15), ('u', 0.14), ('n', 0.08)]
   Top 5 'negative' letters in eigenword 1: [('a', -0.72), ('l', -0.41), ('y', -0.06), ('k', -0.04), ('b', -0.02)]
   Vector product ranked words ['intro', 'round', 'curio', 'rhino']
   Squared error ranked words  ['error', 'rotor', 'onion', 'eerie']

Eigenword 2
   Top 5 'positive' letters in eigenword 2: [('i', 0.53), ('e', 0.4), ('l', 0.24), ('n', 0.16), ('d', 0.08)]
   Top 5 'negative' letters in eigenword 2: [('o', -0.4), ('r', -0.38), ('a', -0.35), ('c', -0.09), ('t', -0.08)]
   Vector product ranked words ['elfin', 'linen', 'glide', 'liken']
   Squared error ranked words  ['linen', 'elide', 'liege', 'exile']

9% of variation is captured by the first 1 eigenwords.
17% of variation is captured by the first 2 eigenwords.
25% of variation is captured by the first 3 eigenwords.
33% of variation is captured by the first 4 eigenwords.
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Actually, never mind that, what even is the mathematical basis for this…? Can you give an interpretation for the sum of two words?

Comment: In [this question on puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/114316/whats-the-optimal-strategy-for-wordle) there is an optimal strategy based on tree search, essentially choosing the word that splits the remaining choices as evenly as possible.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan! I didn't even know there was a puzzling stack exchange site.  This question might be a better fit there.

Comment: See the essay by Brian Hayes: http://bit-player.org/2022/words-for-the-wordle-weary

Comment: Personally, it is hard for me to imagine a better first word guess than $$I ~~D~~E~~A~~L.$$  (Very subjectively), I feel that nailing down the vowels is half the battle.  Reasonable alternatives might be $$A~~C~~U~~T~~E  ~~\text{or}~~ A~~D~~O~~R~~E.$$  *ACUTE* has the advantage of combining the **frequent** vowels of A,E with the infrequent vowel of U.  *IDEAL* and *ADORE* each have the advantage of (also) using one of the **liquid** consonants : *L* or *R*, each of which often combine with selected other consonants.